# SMTP server setup on windows xp, IIS

Tags: smtp, newsletters

I have my domain registered with godaddy. I want to send newsletter to my customers (around 5000). But there is limit to send number of emails per day.

1. Can i setup SMTP server on my home PC (windows XP) for sending these mails.
2. Is there any "open source"/Free newsletter management application (build on ASP.NET, so that i can customize it if needed) which track bounce emails and other analytics.
3. Any issue which i have to take care.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you want to send bulk (legitimate) emails, it's generally best to go to one of the many bulk-send providers than doing it yourself.  That's just my opinion, but you avoid a LOT of headaches with setup, blacklisting avoidance, etc.  Most good ones will provide some analytics.